# convert struts2 iterator into *.json file

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, struts2

This is iterator holding bank details.

```
<s:iterator value="bankDetailsList">
    <tr>
        <td><s:property value="Date"/></td>
        <td><s:property value="Description"/></td>
        <td><s:property value="Debit" /></td>
        <td><s:property value="Credit" /></td>
        <td><s:property value="Balance" /></td>
    </tr>
</s:iterator>
```

i want to convert this iterator into *.json.
can anyone do this or help me ?.
thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) JSP can produce any output you want; it's just text. 2) Why? Use a JSON result.

Comment: i want show data on table format but first need to convert json format so convert this iterator into json data after use it.